# How to sell boss software I've made off-time?

Tags: productivity

I've made, off-time, a simple software tool that cuts about 1/4th off of a repetitive procedure I do at my data-entry job. Upper management is very adamant that they're a "Pay-for-Performance" company.

I've shown my boss (and his boss, and the IT dept) the software, and they love it.

Do I just give it to them, hoping I get a nice raise next year? Or, do I try to license it to my boss? How do I go about getting compensated? I'm NOT a "creative employee"--I was hired just to do data-entry.

(I only used the company's resources to write down ideas when they came to me. Other than adding items to my "To-Do" list, I haven't used their equipment at all).

I'm actually taking a two-year leave next year, but they've already told me I'll have a job waiting when I come back. So, I could negotiate a salary increase this year, or say "When I come back, can you promise me I'll be making $XX,XXX?"

Comment: you pour fellow, doing data entry would drive me insane.

Comment: This is not on-topic here.  It might be somewhat on-topic on https://workplace.stackexchange.com This question isn't about a computer problem. You are asking for both legal and business advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation where best practice would be to consult a lawyer. What you want to do is you want to ensure that you fully "own" the software in question without any kind of confusion. At this point, once you've established ownership (presumably through copyright) you can go whatever way you want with it. You can either offer to license it to them, or sell it outright including copyright. They may not like the idea of licensing it if there is a competitive market in your industry, as licensing it means that you would be able to also license it to your competitors.

If you want to "give" it to them, then do yourself a favor and save yourself pain later...publish the software as "open source" under something like the Apache license or the GPL license (depending on which exact license it conforms to) and then give it to them. This will prevent them from waiting six months and then licensing that software out themselves and making money off of your idea without your benefit. Remember that as much as your supervisor and his fellows may like you, the business is in business to make money, not to be your friend. If the company doesn't want the software open source, then you should absolutely sell it to them. Even if you do so for a relatively small amount of money, you should be compensated in some way.

Just be sure to ensure that you own the software first, otherwise they will likely just take what you have and give you nothing, which is a story so many developers have lived through over the years.

Comment: Thank you! What you said gives me food for thought. I never thought about open-source-ing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to stay with your current position or move to a programming position. If you want to stay, ask for money. If you want a promotion, give it to them with the argument just think how much I could save you if... and present your next project.